# UK Tourist Visa validity for first entry

Tags: visas, uk

I have received a UK tourist visa (Multiple Entries) issued on 25th January and valid until 25 July. I have plans to go in June/July.

Is there any validity requirement for making my first entry into the UK, as in some countries where you have to make first entry in a certain time period? Can I enter the UK any time between 25th January and 25th July?

Answer (score 2):

> Or I can enter UK any time between 25th January and 25th July.

Yes, but you would have to be out of the country before the 26th of July.