# UK visa: when does my first entry date have to be?

Tags: uk, family

I have just been granted a 2-year multiple-entry UK visa. My first trip to the UK is not planned until August. I have just heard that I have to enter the UK within 90 days of my family visit visa issue date. Does anyone know if this is correct?

Comment: Heard from who/where?

Comment: From [this old question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/86989/uk-tourist-visa-validity-for-first-entry) it looks like no, there's no entry date restriction. But no idea if that's authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

> I have just heard that I have to enter the UK within 90 days of my family visit visa issue date.

That is not correct, there is no such requirement: your visa is valid from the fixed start date noted on the visa and remains valid until the indicated end date. You are allowed multiple entries, for up to 6 months on each trip.